# Powershell SQL Timeout

Tags: sql-server, powershell, powershell-4.0

I have the following code

```
    ## - Get SQL Server Table data:
$SQLServer = 'random';
$Database = 'random';
$SqlQuery = 'EXEC [random].[LandMarkGlobalExport]';

## - Connect to SQL Server using non-SMO class 'System.Data':
$SqlConnection = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection;
$SqlConnection.ConnectionString = `
"Server = $SQLServer; Database = $Database; Integrated Security = True";

$SqlCmd = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand;
$SqlCmd.CommandText = $SqlQuery;
$SqlCmd.Connection = $SqlConnection;

## - Extract and build the SQL data object '$DataSetTable':
$SqlAdapter = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter;
$SqlAdapter.SelectCommand = $SqlCmd;
$DataSet = New-Object System.Data.DataSet;
$SqlAdapter.Fill($DataSet);
$DataSetTable = $DataSet.Tables["Table"];

## ---------- Working with Excel ---------- ##

## - Create an Excel Application instance:
$xlsObj = New-Object -ComObject Excel.Application;

## - Create new Workbook and Sheet (Visible = 1 / 0 not visible)
$xlsObj.Visible = 0;
$xlsWb = $xlsobj.Workbooks.Add();
$xlsSh = $xlsWb.Worksheets.item(1);

## - Copy entire table to the clipboard as tab delimited CSV
```

However I am getting the following error

> Exception calling "Fill" with "1" argument(s): "Execution Timeout
> Expired.  The timeout period elapsed prior to completion of the
> operation or the server is not responding." At line:19 char:1
>
> - $SqlAdapter.Fill($DataSet);
> - ```
>     + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
>     + FullyQualifiedErrorId : SqlException
>   ```

For $SqlAdapter.Fill($DataSet); - how can I stop the timout?

Any help appreciated

Comment: Have you tried setting the [CommandTimeout property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.commandtimeout) on the SqlCommand object? It defaults to 30 seconds, so perhaps you could look at performance tuning the LandMarkGlobalExport stored procedure as well.

Comment: Thanks AlwaysLearning yes thatwb as the issue.. set it to $SqlCmd.CommandTimeout = 0; and it works.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47073578/powershell-sql-server-database-connectivity-and-connection-timeout-issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue turned out to be user permission to write the Excel file.